# What is the wind drag created by a solar panel on RV?

Tags: aerodynamics

I installed my solar panel a couple weeks ago and now I'm not sure if I did it right. This pic is not mine but it’s what brought up the curiosity, as this guy has the same trailer and the same 200w panel as i do.

See how the panel is sticking out over the front where the teardrop is curved, it seems like it would catch a lot of air like that. So, when I installed mine I did it at a 90 degree rotation to this and installed it lengthwise so its parallel to, and even with the roof bars. My thoughts are since it’s on the flat portion of the trailer by that point it would not catch as much wind as it would facing over the curve and digging into the wind.

I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask this but it’s about physics and drag, and I figure someone on here is smart enough to help figure out which way of mounting is more aerodynamic.

[image: panel mounted short ways]

Answer (score 1):

The primary drag source in this case is *profile* or "frontal area" drag. To estimate the effect of adding the solar panels, measure & compute the frontal area presented to the air by the leading surface of the array and *compare that* to the frontal area of the tow rig. The effect will be small.

Furthermore, note that flow separation is probably occurring at the rear end of your tow rig which puts the solar array inside the boundary layer "shadow" of the tow rig, which means the solar panel is not experiencing the full free-stream velocity of the airflow, and thus it will generate less drag than it would if it was protruding into the free stream.

Comment: He did well by rotating the panel but still I would not be surprised if drag goes up by 10%. Especially if a sedan is towing it.